# Find max on BigDecimal list using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's suppose that I have a class like this :

```
public class A {
    private int id;
    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

And I have a `List<A>`. How can I find the maximum amount of all `A` objects in the list using Java 8 stream ?

This method :

```
List<A> brol = new ArrayList<>();
BigDecimal max = brol.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(A -> A.getAmount())).get().getAmount();
        System.out.println("MAX = " + max);
```

Gives `NoSuchElementException` so I should create a specific comparator for this ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What I would do is check the Optional

```
Optional<BigDecimal> max = brol.stream()
                               .map(a -> a.amount)
                               .max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
if (max.isPresent()) {
   // have a max
}
```

Instead of the `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, you can use `BigDecimal::compareTo` if you feel this is clearer.

The Optional.get() is throwing the `NoSuchElementException` as there is no element. You only need to provide a `Comparator` when the Object you are getting the max is not `Comparable`

In this case, you don't need the maximum `A` only the maximum `amount` which is a `BigDecimal` which is `Comparable`.

You could provide a comparator if you actually wanted the minimum though using `min()` would be a simpler choice in this regard.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: OP is getting a `NoSuchElementException` because he is getting the max value of an empty list, which indeed returns an `Optional.empty` (as there is no item to return). As long as the list has at least 1 item the exception should be gone. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--) about `max()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey the `.max()` method should receive a `Comparator` as parameter, no ?

Comment: @GrechkaVassili No, because due to `map()` it's comparing `BigDecimal` which implements `Comparable`.

Comment: @Kayaman @PeterLawrey Thank you, I've solved my problem but when I try your solution `Optional<BigDecimal> maximum = brol.stream().map(A -> A.getAmount()).max();`, Intellij gives me this error : `method max in interface java.util.stream.Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types` and it says that the `max()` method should receive a `java.util.Comparator<? super.java.math.BigDecimal>`....

Comment: Ah darn, there *isn't* a non-comparator taking `max()` for comparables. You do need the comparator then.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a specific comparator for this.  The comparator is not your problem.

The fluent style of invocations is nice and hip and trendy, but it has one major disadvantage which many seem to overlook: when an error happens somewhere along this train of function calls, you have no clue where it happened.

So, in order to troubleshoot such problems, it is best to break down the fluent train into individual wagons.  (At least for the troubleshooting, and put it back into a train if you want after, all troubleshooting is done.)

In which case you will see that `max()` returns an `Optional<BigDecimal>`, and it is `Optional` because if your `ArrayList` `brol` is empty, (and in the example you provided, it is empty,) then there is no max, because the `max` operation is undefined on an empty list.

So, you need to provide for the case that your `ArrayList` is empty.  You can do this before invoking `stream().max()`, or you can do it as Peter Lawrey suggested, by invoking the `isPresent()` method of the `Optional`.

By the way, the fact that you made this error shows that either:

- You are using some outdated build tools that are incapable of giving you warnings about your code, or
- You do not have all warnings enabled, or
- You receive warnings but you ignore them.

Don't do that, you will never get very far this way.  My IntelliJ IDEA gives me a warning (JetBrains calls it "inspection") on your code saying that `.get()` was invoked without `.isPresent()`.  So, I can immediately tell what's wrong with the code before compiling it, before running it, before troubleshooting it, and before asking a stackoverflow question about it.

Comment: You are right ! Sorry sometimes you can't get somethink working because of an inattention error. My `brol` list was declared just after another `List<A>` and was in fact empty. I'm also using Intellij and I had the error `Optional.get() without isPresent()`...

Answer (score 0):

Use stream with `orElse` to provide some fallback or default value.

```
BigDecimal maxValue = brol.stream()
  .map(a -> a.amount)
  .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
  .orElse(null); // you can also use BigDecimal.ZERO here instead of null
```